# HTML5 video tag file not supported

Tags: javascript, html, video

```html
<div class="row video-box">
  <div class="col-lg-12 vid-full">
     <video controls id="vid-delay" class="video" loop controls>
       <source src="../assets/images/vid-ocean-pine2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
       <source src="../assets/images/vid-ocean-pine2.ogg" type="video/ogg">
       <source src="../assets/images/vid-ocean-pine2.webm" type="video/webm" />
       <source src="../assets/images/vid-ocean-pine2.H.264" type="video/H.264" />
       Your browser does not support the video tag.
     </video>
     <div id="vid_box"><div class="playpause"></div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I am using HTML video tag to try and play a video file on my website. I have several fallbacks in place; .mp4, ogg, webm, h.264 but still all browsers are complaining that file is not supported. Has anyone encountered this issue or is aware how to resolve? The file path should be also correct as other stuff referenced from the files is pulling through fine. Not sure where else to look to resolve this. Could anyone be so kind to share some light on this?

Here's the site url:

http://www.gtechwebmasters.co.uk/

Comment: Please post the relevant code here. We're not going to parse through your entire site's code. Also, upon opening your site and checking the console, it is evident that your file paths are wrong as there are 6 404 errors corresponding to each of your video files.

Comment: please see code snippet above

Comment: Has your server been configured with the appropriate mime types? If not, it won't serve the files.

Comment: "The file path should be also correct" — **look at the URLs**. It clearly isn't. You have 404 errors.

Comment: ok so full path is /evolutionroofingltd/ocean_pine_v1/ocean_pine/assets/images what should the ref be in my html? i have tried every option

Comment: Again, if your server is not configured with the proper mime types, the files will not be served even when the paths are correct. This will result in 404 errors.

Comment: bingo! Scott! server config it was. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your server is not configured with the proper mime types, the files will not be served even when the paths are correct. This will result in 404 errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your video sources are not accessible. Look at [this one](http://www.gtechwebmasters.co.uk/assets/images/vid-ocean-pine2.mp4) for example, when you open it on your browser, 404 error displayed. So maybe the sources are not exists on your server, or unreachable because of server configuration.

If you sure that the sources are in the right path, make them reachable. Use [aspnet_regiis.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h(VS.80).aspx) to register version of .NET framework you are using.